# MPDF57 CSS3 list-style:none not being applied (or isn't supported) for <UL> items inside <TD> element

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, mpdf

I would like to clear [`list-style-type:circle;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) from the generated PDF (using [MPDF57](https://web.archive.org/web/20180224101502/http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)). I've read the [CSS3 Docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20151022021654/http://mpdf1.com:80/manual/index.php?tid=34) (and according to the documentation, [`list-style:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) is supported), but during the `Output()` stage of creating a PDF file,  the `circle` can seen.

**HTML OUTPUT**
[image: HTML RENDER]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/rlap1byo.ock.png))</sub>

*Border* is to only emphasize, which elements are being targeted.

**PDF OUTPUT**
[image: PDF FILE]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/qhqyh0xn.nkr.png))</sub>

**CSS** (*HTML* available via [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/Gr8g6eV7)).

```
.schedule_logo_con img {
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
.daily_schedule { font-family: helvetica, sans serif }
.schedule {
    font-family: helvetica, sans serif;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.schedule_list { margin: 10px 0 0 0 }
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.weekday {
    width: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    border-left: solid #ddd 1px;
    color: red;
}
.weekday ul li {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
ul, .weekday ul, .weekday ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I've also tried [`list-style-type:none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) (In addition too checking `MPDF56` to see whether it is something with `MPDF57`), but regardless this style is not being applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it seems to be a rendition problem, from the library itself

**`<UL>` with no parents**

But, the above CSS does work, if the UL element is being generated on its own, and not as a child of a another element.

```
<ul>
<li>Test A</li>
<li>Test B</li>
</ul>
```

**PDF OUTPUT**

[image: PDF NO CHILDREN]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/tr4bx4lp.ytt.png))</sub>

**Solution**

Therefore, the designer and I have a found a work around, using `divs` and replicating a list with `display:block;`, although if someone is able to figure out a solution for `<UL>`, without high server load (That would be great too).

*CSS*

```
div.weekday_time {
    display:block;
}
```

*HTML*

```
<div class='weekday_time'>
    10:30 PM
</div>
```

Comment: 6 years later I can confirm that it is still the case